# nginx 1.12.2 not binding to ports on Centos 7.4

Tags: nginx, centos7, port

I have installed nginx via yum on Centos 7.4. I've added some sites to `/etc/nginx/conf.d` that listen on port 80. Here is an example:

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /var/www/vhosts/somesite;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name api.somesite.info;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/impro.somesite.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

nginx -t returns:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

The service is started as follows:

```
systemctl start nginx
```

This returns no errors. And there is no firewall installed at present.

The problem is that even if I point `/etc/hosts` at api.somesite.info I am getting a refused connection.

To see the ports bound, I ran `netstat -ltnep`, giving:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       
User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          14585      1/systemd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          18224      1105/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          16689      979/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          68092      4930/php-fpm: maste
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      27         51441      26589/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          14584      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          18226      1105/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          16690      979/master
```

So while php-fpm has bound to a port (I'm actually mostly using sockets, but that's not relevant here I don't think), nginx has not. Note that there is nothing listening to port 80 - apache is not installed by default in this version of centos.

I can see that nginx is running by running `systemctl status nginx`:

```
nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-04-04 15:24:04 BST; 4min 8s ago
Process: 6091 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 6088 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 6086 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6094 (nginx)
 CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
       ├─6094 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
       └─6095 nginx: worker process

Apr 04 15:24:04 smaractus systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Apr 04 15:24:04 smaractus nginx[6088]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Apr 04 15:24:04 smaractus nginx[6088]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Apr 04 15:24:04 smaractus systemd[1]: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Apr 04 15:24:04 smaractus systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
```

I can see a warning here where it fails to find the pid file, but as far as I understand that's not a show stopper? Out of ideas as to where to look now. Why is nginx not binding port 80?

Comment: Nginx is exiting, check the nginx logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you happen to see this in `nginx.conf`?

```
    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

This means that the name of the file in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` must end with `.conf`. Check the file's name and rename it so that it ends with `.conf`. With any other name it will be ignored.

Comment: Hurray! How you worked this out from what I gave I don't know, but spot on! Checking the system I was migrating from I previously had include `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*`, which of course does not make the same requirement.

Comment: @RobertEgginton We don't need `sites-enabled`, as simply renaming the file is sufficient to disable it. I've always thought that particular Debianism made things overly complicated.